# Strange error in Mono on ubuntu using MonoDev

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, monodevelop

I have the following line:

```
associatedGuiElements.listElements.Sort(Function(x, y) x.zIndex.CompareTo(y.zIndex))
```

Now, the line is just supposed to sort the list by a property (zIndex).  It works fine in Windows using VS but when I imported the project into Mono, this is the only line it has problems with.  Can anybody explain why?  The error message is:

> /media/FreeAgent Drive/HalfDime Engine/HalfDime
>   Engine/Engine/HalfDime_Engine.vb(74,74): Error VBNC99999: Unexpected
>   error: There has been an internal error in the compiler: (VBNC99999)
>   (HalfDime Engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the actual VB.NET compiler has a bug that caused it to crash. Your best bet is to file a bug with a simple test case in the [Novell Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.novell.com/)